# Radio Buttons are being grouped while having different id's JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create some questions where you can choose an option from 1 to 5.

I am doing this using radio buttons, and I also change their ID so that they are not the same entity.

Although I am first creating the first question and after the other one, for some reason all the radio buttons are connected and I can only choose 1 button out of the 10 if I create 2 questions, and not 1 from the first question and 1 from the next one.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Check my code below to see the problem. Thanks

This is my code:

```js
const questionnaire = document.getElementById('questionaire');

var numsQN = 0;

questionnaire.onclick = ev => {
    if (ev.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
        switch (ev.target.className) {
            case "remove-qu":
                switch (ev.target.parentNode.className) {
                    case "numQuestion":
                        numsQN--;
                        document.getElementById('numberOfNumQuestions').innerHTML = "Number Questions = " + numsQN;
                        break;
                }
                ev.target.parentNode.remove();
                break;
            case "add-numli":
                newNumSubquestion(ev.target.closest(".starQuestion").querySelector('ul'), false)
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        switch (ev.target.className) {
            case "remove-numli":
                ev.target.parentNode.remove();
                break;
        }
    }
}

function newNumQuestion() {
    questionnaire.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <div class='numQuestion'> <div class="numbers"> <ul></ul> </div>`);
}

function newNumSubquestion(q, subquestionNumber) {
    q.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
        <li class="numSubquestion"> 
        <span class="numSubquestionName">Sub-question</span> 
        <div id='colourRadioButtons'> </div>`);

    var element = document.getElementById("colourRadioButtons");
    var newName = "colourRadioButtons" + subquestionNumber + "";
    element.id = newName;

    let lastRadio = false;

    const numbers = { "5": false, "4": false, "3": false, "2": false, "1": false, },
        radioStatic = {
            name: "colour", onchange: (event) => {
                if (lastRadio) {
                    numbers[lastRadio] = false;
                }
                lastRadio = event.currentTarget.value;
                numbers[lastRadio] = event.currentTarget.checked;
            }, type: "radio"
        }; // radioStatic

    for (let key in numbers) {
        element.appendChild(
            Object.assign(document.createElement("label"), { textContent: key })).appendChild(
                Object.assign(document.createElement("input"), radioStatic, { checked: numbers[key], value: key }));
        if (numbers[key]) {
            lastRadio = key;
        }
    }
}

function generateNumberQuestion() {
    let howManyOptionEachNumsQuestionHas = 2;
    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        newNumQuestion(true);
        for (let j = 0; j < howManyOptionEachNumsQuestionHas; j++) {
            newNumSubquestion(questionnaire.querySelector("div.numQuestion:last-child ul"), j);
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById("addNumButton").onclick = function () { generateNumberQuestion(); };
```

```html
    
     <h1 id="myText" contenteditable="true">Survey Name</h1>
  <button type="button" id="addNumButton">Number Rating</button>
  <form>
    <div id="questionaire"></div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Radio buttons are group by the name attribute not the id attribute [see the W3C school page for examples](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp)

Comment: Because they all have the same `name`.  Which ultimately determines what value is sent to the server.  So even if you were to make them separately grouped somehow, the second group's value would shadow the first group's value when posting the form.  **Edit:** In fact... *"while having different id's"* - They don't have `id`s at all.  How do you plan to differentiate the first `<input name="colour" type="radio" value="1">` from the second `<input name="colour" type="radio" value="1">` for example?

Comment: Alright, I found it guys, thanks!